# Прототипное наследование

Tags: javascript, ооп, prototype

Добрый День. Изучаю способы организации наследования в JavaScript и написал небольшой пример :

```
  function Foo(name) {
    this.name = name;
}

Foo.prototype.myName = function() {
    return this.name;
};

function Bar(name, label) {
    Foo.call(this, name);
    this.label = label;
}

Bar.prototype = Foo.prototype;

Bar.prototype.myLabel = function() {
    return this.label;
};

var a = new Bar("a", "obj a");

a.myName();
a.myLabel();
```

Вопрос возник на строке :

```
Bar.prototype = Foo.prototype;
```

Пытаясь понять разницу между

```
Bar.prototype = new Foo()
```

и

```
Bar.prototype = Foo.prototype;
```

набрел на статью, в которой говориться

> Bar.prototype = Foo.prototype doesn't create a new object for Bar.prototype to be linked to. It just makes Bar.prototype be another reference to Foo.prototype, which effectively links Bar directly to the same object as Foo links to: Foo.prototype. This means when you start assigning, like Bar.prototype.myLabel = ..., you're modifying not a separate object but the shared Foo.prototype object itself, which would affect any objects linked to Foo.prototype.

Вопрос заключается в последнем предложении. Почему при добавлении прототипу свойства Bar, мы автоматически меняем и прототип объекта Foo ? Если я правильно понял, то как раз при добавлении свойства или метода в объект Foo, должен измениться и объект Bar, т.к. он ссылается на прототип Foo. Помогите разобраться пожалуйста.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Давайте начнем с отвлеченного примера:

```js
var a = {
  test: 11
}
b = a;

b.test = 12;
console.log(a.test); // Выведет 12!
```

Это происходит потому, что объекты в JS присваиваются и передаются *по ссылке* а не по значению.

Свойство `<An Object>.prototype` - это объект. Когда вы выполняете код:

```
Bar.prototype = Foo.prototype;
```

вы присваиваете свойству `Bar.prototype` *ссылку* на объект `Foo.prototype`. Как следствие, любое изменение свойства `Bar.prototype` приводит к изменению `Foo.prototype`, о чем и говорится в приведнной цитате:

> This means when you start assigning, like Bar.prototype.myLabel = ..., you're modifying not a separate object but the shared Foo.prototype object itself, which would affect any objects linked to Foo.prototype.

---

Небольшое **лирическое отступление**.

Вообще говоря, я бы рекомендовал вам **никогда** не использовать конструкцию:

```
Bar.prototype = new Foo();
```

а всех тех, кто вам это советует -- смело *отправляйте учить основы JS*. Вся соль в том, что вызывая `new Foo()` вы вызываете конструктор объекта. При этом сам конструктор может с одной стороны накладывать ограничения на передаваемые аргументы, а с другой иметь побочные действия. Разберем каждый из этих случаев отдельно.

Предположим, у вас есть вот такой конструктор, накладывающий ограничения на свои аргументы:

```
Foo = function(a) {
    if (typeof a === 'undefined') {
        throw new Error('You have to set the first argument.');
    }

    this.a = a;
}
```

В этом случае вы уже не можете просто взять и выполнить:

```
Bar.prototype = new Foo();
```

т.к. вам нужно в явном виде предать аргумент в конструктор, который полностью лишен смысла в момент описания иерархии наследования. Самое интересное, что значение параметра `a` все равно будет затерто при вызове конструктора `Foo` в дочернем конструкторе `Bar`. Поэтому конструкция `new Foo()` еще и лишена смысла.

Теперь предположим, что родительский конструктор имеет побочные эффекты:

```
Foo = function(a) {
    console.log('Here I am!');
}
```

При использовании:

```
Bar.prototype = new Foo();
```

и дальнейшем:

```
var Bar = function() {
    Foo.call(this);
}
```

строка "`Here I am!`" будет выведена **дважды**. Согласитесь, это не всегда желаемое поведение системы.

Ну и еще один любопытный факт: даже если *сейчас* родительский конструктор не имеет ни побочных эффектов, ни ограничений на аргументы, это не значит, что он останется таким *навсегда*. Лучше уж сразу сделать все правильно, чем нервно отлаживать код в поисках ошибки, когда все сломается.

---

Приведу, для справки, **правильную реализацию** наследования в JS:

```
// Базовый конструктор
var Foo = function() {
    // ...
};

Foo.prototype.doSomething = function() {
    // ...
};

// Дочерний конструктор
var Bar = function() {
    // Вызываем базовый конструктор для текущего объекта.
    Foo.call(this);
    // ...
};

// Устанавливаем правильное значение в цепочке прототипов.
Bar.prototype = Object.create(Foo.prototype, {
    // Выставляем правильную функцию-конструктор для всех создаваемых
    // объектов.
    constructor: {
        value: Bar,
        enumerable: false,
        writable: true,
        configurable: true
    }
});

// Расширяем прототип дочернего "класса". Этот шаг должен идти
// СТРОГО ПОСЛЕ установки значения Bar.prototype.
Bar.prototype.doAnotherAction = function() {
    // ...
};
```

В случае, когда вы не можете использовать `Object.create` (старые браузеры) вы можете либо использовать один из существующих полифилов, либо сделать все ручками(через анонимный конструктор):

```
var inherits = function(ctor, superCtor) {
    // Временный конструктор, который не делает ничего и нужен
    // только для разрыва прямой связи между прототипами ctor
    // и superCtor. Его использование позволяет менять прототип
    // дочернего конструктора, не боясь сломать родительский.
    var Tmp = function() {};
    Tmp.prototype = superCtor.prototype;

    // Обратите внимание, вызов new Tmp() не имеет АБСОЛЮТНО
    // никаких побочных эффектов и не накладывает ограничений
    // на передаваемые значения.
    ctor.prototype = new Tmp();
    // Выставляем правильную функцию-конструктор для всех
    // создаваемых объектов.
    ctor.prototype.constructor = ctor;
};
```

---

С учетом всего выше сказанного универсальная функции наследования может иметь вид:

```
var inherits = (function() {
    if (typeof Object.create === 'function') {
       // Используем более простой вариант, если Object.create существует.
       return function(ctor, superCtor) {
           ctor.prototype = Object.create(superCtor.prototype, {
               constructor: {
                   value: ctor,
                   enumerable: false,
                   writable: true,
                   configurable: true
               }
           });
       };
    }

    // Используем временный конструктор для старых браузеров
    return function(ctor, superCtor) {
        var Tmp = function() {};
        Tmp.prototype = superCtor.prototype;
        ctor.prototype = new Tmp();
        ctor.prototype.constructor = ctor;
    };
})();
```

**UPD:**

В реализациях выше, после присваивания прототипа, задается свойство [`Function.prototype.constructor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/constructor). Хотя это свойство редко используется на практике (лично я ни разу не видел в production коде), полноценная реализация наследования должна его выставлять.

Comment: из объяснения вообще непонятно, что же плохого в `Bar.prototype = new Foo();` - что-то вроде если вы делаете так, и при этом то-то и то-то то все плохо, а если этих то-то и то-то не будет?

Comment: В любом случае, при `Bar.prototype = new Foo();`  конструктор `Foo` вызывается **дважды**. Даже если его вызов не имеет побочных эффектов, один из вызовов _полностью лишен смысла_. Ну и тот факт, что _сейчас_ конструктор `Foo` не имеет побочных эффектов, не значит, что он не будет иметь их в будущем. Я бы не хотел поддерживать код, который может внезапно сломаться.

Comment: _любой_ код может внезапно сломаться :) он вызывается дважды только потому, что мы его вызываем дважды. Если вызывать его один раз он будет вызываться один раз :)

Comment: @Grundy, обновил ответ. А что касается двойного вызова, то если вам нравится плодить костыли -- это ваше право. На мой взгляд лучше все сразу сделать _правильно_, особенно с учетом крошечного оверхеда в вызове `Object.create`

Comment: Если бы все было так просто :)

Comment: @Grundy, что ж тут сложного: `Object.create(Foo.prototype)` вместо `new Foo()`...

Comment: Это я про _все сразу сделать правильно_ :-D

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36408/discussion-between-dmitriy-simushev-and-grundy).

Answer (score 7):

Если вы используете ES6, то можно использовать для наследования стандартные средства языка:

```
// Базовый класс
class Foo {
    doSomething() {
        // ...
    }
}

// Дочерний класс, наследующий все поведение базового +
// методы определенные ниже.
class Bar extends Foo {
    doAnotherAction() {
        // ...
    }
}
```