# Маленькие Javascript библиотеки ООП?

Tags: javascript, ооп

Какие есть маленькие и быстрые библиотеки ООП javascript. Которые позволяют создавать классы, наследоваться от них? В таком вот стиле.

```
    // объявляем класс
    Lib.defineClass('имя_класса' ,{ 
    extend: 'родительский_класс', // наследуемся от родительский_класс
    myProp: [1,2]
    });

   // Создаём экземпляр(объект) класса с типом имя_класса, заменяя свойство myProp.
    var cls = Lib.createClass('имя_класса' ,{
    myProp: [1,2,3,4],
    myProp2: 'свойство экземпляра класса'
    });

    cls.myProp[0]; // 1
    Lib.имя_класса; // созданный класс доступен как объект где нибудь.
    Lib.имя_класса.myProp[0]; // 1
```

Comment: насколько библиотека должна быть маленькой и на сколько быстрой? что происходит в приведенном куске кода? чем не устраивает нативная реализация?

Comment: Мне нужна такая же реализация как в Ext js. Но чтобы файл весил не 1 мб, а не больше 30 kb, и не был тормозным.

Пример дополнил. Вначале объявляем класс, затем создаём объект класса, затем осуществляем доступ к его свойству.

Comment: Самая маленькая в 0 килобайт — `Object.create`.

Comment: Dean Edwards’s Base Library

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На самом деле, вам **совсем** не нужны сторонние библиотеки.

Если пишете ES6 код, то можно использовать стандартные средства языка:

```
class Foo {
    constructor() {
        this.greeting = 'Hi all';
    }

    sayHi() {
        console.log(this.greeting);
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
    sayHi() {
        console.log(this.greeting + ' from bar');
    }
}
```

Если вы все еще не начали использовать ES6, то функция, эмулирующая классовое наследование занимает всего (внимание) **10 строк**. Я уже описывал как именно работает наследование в JavaScript вот в [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/498689/182771). А здесь просто приведу код функции наследования:

```
var inherits = function(ctor, superCtor) {
    ctor.prototype = Object.create(superCtor.prototype, {
        constructor: {
            value: ctor,
            enumerable: false,
            writable: true,
            configurable: true
        }
    });
}
```

Ну и для определения классов вполне подходят стандартные средства языка.

Answer (score 1):

Может быть подойдёт [JS.Class](http://dkraczkowski.github.io/js.class/)
Или можно поискать что то ещё на [www.microjs.com](http://microjs.com/)