# Javascript. Что происходит в этом куске кода?

Tags: javascript, node.js, объекты, prototype, export

Первый раз вижу такой код.. не пойму, что тут происходит?

```
var DemoAppModel = (function (_super) {
    __extends(DemoAppModel, _super);

    function DemoAppModel() {
        _super.call(this);   
    }

    DemoAppModel.prototype.auth = function () {}

    return DemoAppModel; 
})(observable.Observable);

exports.DemoAppModel = DemoAppModel;
exports.mainViewModel = new DemoAppModel();
```

Где про это можно прочитать?

Comment: Это транспилированный код какого-то фреймворка, реализация модели, где вы нашли этот код?

Comment: Это из какого-то плагина к nativescript или node.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Это полифил для реализация наследования в версиях до ES6.

---

До преобразования транспилятором (скорее всего речь идет о [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/index.html)) этот код (как верно [отметил](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/621530/182771) **@Pavel Mayorov**) имел вид:

```
export class DemoAppModel extends observable.Observable {
    auth() { }
}
export var mainViewModel = new DemoAppModel();
```

Давайте разберемся что-здесь происходит строчка за строчкой:

```
// Создаем IIFE(*1), возвращающую конструктор класса DemoAppModel
// Аргумент "_super" - конструктор родительского класса.
var DemoAppModel = (function (_super) {
    // Выставляем правильную цепочку прототипов для вновь созданного
    // конструктора(*2).
    // Обратите внимание, "DemoAppModel" здесь - это функция определенная
    // строчкой ниже, а не функция из предыдущей области видимости(*3).
    __extends(DemoAppModel, _super);

    // Определяем нашу функцию конструктор.
    function DemoAppModel() {
        // Вызываем родительский конструктор в контексте вновь созданного
        // экземпляра DemoAppModel. Это необходимо для правильной
        // инициализации переменных экземпляра, определенных через 
        // родительский конструктор.
        _super.call(this);   
    }

    // Создаем новый метод для экземпляров DemoAppModel, который ничего
    // не делает.
    DemoAppModel.prototype.auth = function () {}

    // Возвращаем созданный конструктор.
    return DemoAppModel;
// Вызываем IIFE(*1) передавая конструктор родительского класса в качестве
// аргумента.
})(observable.Observable);

// Экспорт функции конструктора и созданного с его помощью экземпляра
// для использования в других модулях.
exports.DemoAppModel = DemoAppModel;
exports.mainViewModel = new DemoAppModel();
```

**Замечания:**

1. [*IIEF*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression)(Immediately-invoked function expression) - функция, которая вызывается сразу же, как только она определена.
2. В общем случае, функция `__extends` имеет вид (без полифила для ES<5):

   ```
      function __extends(ctor, superCtor) {
          ctor.prototype = Object.create(superCtor.prototype, {
              constructor: {
                  value: ctor,
                  enumerable: false,
                  writable: true,
                  configurable: true
              }
          });
      };
   ```

   Что именно здесь происходит несколько выходит за рамки вопроса и требует отдельного дополнительного обсуждения.
3. В JavaScript мы можем использовать функции до момента их определения благодаря "[*Поднятию определения*](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8C/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5)".

Некоторое время назад я уже рассказывал, как именно работает прототипное наследование в JavaScript вот в [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/498689/182771). Там есть чуть больше деталей о самой логике реализации прототипного наследования.

Answer (score 2):

Это код, сгенерированный компилятором TypeScript. До компиляции он был вот таким:

```
export class DemoAppModel extends observable.Observable {
  auth() { }
}
export var mainViewModel = new DemoAppModel();
```

Никакой магии, просто создается класс-наследник другого с одним пустым методом и объект этого класса.

Answer (score 1):

Обычный класс какого-то плагина аля [Babel](http://babeljs.io)(он преобразовывает синтаксис es5-es6-es7 в код который должен поддерживаться в старых браузерах). Прочитайте про [es5 классы](http://learn.javascript.ru/es-class). Сразу увидите схожесть реализации. Сначала класс создали, потом сделали наследование, потом вызвали конструктор который наследует все от от родителя. А потом создали новый метод auth.

Comment: Babel генерирует не такой код. Это компилятор Typescript постарался.

Comment: @Pavel Я поэтому и сказал "какого-то плагина аля", я не могу знать точно чей это код.