# Классы и метод apply

Tags: javascript

Вопрос по поводу `apply`: можете описать более подробно какие аргументы должны передаваться в `apply` и какого общее предназначение?

Читал что устанавливает стандартное значение для `this`: так вопрос, в `apply` обязательно должен передаваться `this` первым аргументом, а вторым - значение, или как?

Толкового в сети ничего не нашел.

```
var Person, anotherPerson, thirdPerson;

Person = function(name) {
    this.name = name;
};

thirdPerson = function(name, skills) {
    Person.apply(this, arguments);
        this.skills = skills || [];
};

thirdPerson.prototype.constructor = thirdPerson;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Из описания метода apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

> Метод apply() вызывает функцию с указанным значением *this* и аргументами переданными в виде массива (или array-like объекта).

Формальный синтаксис:

```
fun.apply(thisArg, [argsArray])
```

Из этого следует, что *первый параметр* - это значение, которое примет *this* внутри функции.

Второй параметр - это массив аргументов, которые будут переданы в вызываемую функцию.

Вызов

```
Person.apply(this, [name, skills]);
```

Эквивалентен вызову

```
Person(name, skills);
```

за исключением установки *this*.

---

В примере кода в вопросе, вызов `Person.apply(this, arguments);` позволяет вызвать функцию *Person*, указав ей в качестве *this* - конструируемый объект типа *thirdPerson*.

При таком вызове строка

```
this.name = name;
```

добавит свойство *name* в нужный объект. Таким образом результатом конструктора будет объект с двумя полями `name` и `skill`.

```
var obj = new thirdPerson("Name", ["skill"]); 
// obj : { name: Name, skills: ["skill"]}
```

Если убрать эту строку результат будет следующим:

```
var obj = new thirdPerson("Name", ["skill"]); 
// obj : { skills: ["skill"]}
```

Comment: такой вопрос возник:
смотрю уроки Sorax'a (мб знаете), код выше аналогичен его коду.
смысл тогда вызывать метод apply с стандартным значением this, который и так указывает на объект? разве что он еще и arguments передал.
есть ли в этом какой-то смысл?

Comment: Person.apply(this, arguments);
я про это. зачем указывать this значение this? что за бессмыслица?

Comment: @ebaklak, это просто один из вариантов наследования, подробнее смотри следующий [ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/498689/186999) - суть вызова в том, чтобы добавить в создаваемый объект свойства из базового класса, в данном случае `name`

Comment: прочитал статью, немного понял, но это не то:
http://image.prntscr.com/image/8ff94b7ddf63457dbeb7a54fe2e5442c.png
в функции переменной Bar, зачем нам Foo.call(THIS) (??) ведь если оставить просто Foo() ничего не изменится? Foo.call(this) устанавливает для this то же значение, this, которое по идее в функции указывает на глобальный объект (windows)

Comment: @ebaklak, ни зачем. Как я сказал выше - это необходимо просто для того, чтобы в объект `this` добавились поля из _базового_ класса, так как на картинке foo пустая функция - ее вызов можно опустить, плюс выполнение как-нибудь инициализаций, как в примере на картинке - вывод лога на консоль

Comment: спасибо :) наконец понял, что я не зря себе мозги изнашивал

Comment: @ebaklak, обновил ответ, добавил пример на основе кода в вопросе.