# Определение прототипа

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, документация, prototype

Читал [Документация](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Object_prototypes) и нашел

> JavaScript часто описывают как язык прототипного наследования — каждый объект, имеет объект-прототип, который выступает как шаблон, от которого объект наследует методы и свойства.

Правильно ли я понимаю, что объект-прототип - это объект-родитель?

1. В чем отличие объект-прототипа от объект-родителя?
2. В чем отличие прототипного наследования от объектно-ориентированного? Я имею ввиду не то, что указано на [Прототипное наследование](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/498679/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5), а следующее - **пусть есть класс A, который прототипно наследует класс B и есть класс С, который является объектом-родителем A. Как взаимосвязаны класс B и класс С?**

Объект-прототип определяется с помощью `__proto__`, а объект-родитель с помощью `extends`.

Верно ли

```
class C {}
class A extends C {}
B = A.__proto__
```

что после этих операций B === C?

Comment: 15мин - вполне понятно описывает. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aQkgUUmUJy4&ab_channel=%D0%92%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%9C%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BD

Comment: _В чем отличие прототипного наследования от объектно-ориентированного?_ - дай определение что ты понимаешь под прототипным наследованием, а что под объектно-ориентированным наследованием

Comment: а также, добавь свои определения для _объект-прототип_ и _объект-родитель_

Comment: а откуда вообще взялся термин _объект-родитель_?

Comment: @Grundy я обновил вопрос.

Answer (score 0):

Нет такого термина как *объект-родитель*, поэтому на первый вопрос невозможно ответить.

Пример с кодом достаточно просто запустить:

```js
class C {}
class A extends C {}

console.log(A.__proto__ === C)
```